# Linux VLAN-aware bridges and trunk ports

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, vlan

I have an ethernet port attached to a bridge:

```
$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
eth0_bridge     8000.6a612bcc4723   yes     eth0
```

The bridge is VLAN-aware (ie `/sys/class/net/eth0_bridge/bridge/vlan_filtering` is `1`).  I want to be able to add other interfaces to that bridge and assign VLANs to them, like this:

```
ip link set eth1 master eth0_bridge
bridge vlan add dev eth1 vid 10 pvid untagged
```

This should connect untagged traffic on eth1 to VLAN 10 on eth0.  But no traffic gets through until I:

```
bridge vlan add dev eth0 vid 10
```

Once I've done this, then everything works as needed.  But is there no way to tell it that `eth0` is a trunk port on bridge `eth0_bridge` that should carry *all* VLANs and then do the VLAN filtering on egress from the bridge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using the [`bridge vlan`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/iproute2/bridge.8.en.html#bridge_vlan_-_VLAN_filter_list) command, you can add (or delete) a range of VLAN IDs in a single shot. For example:

```
# bridge vlan add vid 2-4094 dev eth0
```

will add all available VLANs to the trunk interface *eth0* (0 and 4095 are reserved in the protocol and must not (nor can) be used, 1 is by default set as PVID untagged VLAN ID, so should be avoided or perhaps better, removed).

```
# bridge vlan show dev eth0
eth0     1 PVID Egress Untagged
         2
         3
[...]
         4093
         4094

# bridge -c vlan show dev eth0
port    vlan ids
eth0     1 PVID Egress Untagged
         2-4094
```

Here `-c` stands for `-c[ompressvlans]` rather than `-c[olor]`: the bridge man page (at least up to iproute2-ss191125) completely lacks information about this option.

Deleting a range works as one could expect:

```
# bridge vlan del vid 100-200 dev eth0
# bridge -c vlan show
port    vlan ids
bridge0  1 PVID Egress Untagged

eth1     1 Egress Untagged
         10 PVID Egress Untagged

eth0     1 PVID Egress Untagged
         2-99
         201-4094
```

Internally all are handled using a ([hashed](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/net/bridge/br_private.h#L163)) list of individual VLANs.

---

Note 1

Cumulus Networks (known to mostly use Linux' native network stack on their network equipments) has some [old](https://docs.cumulusnetworks.com/version/cumulus-linux-31/Layer-1-and-Layer-2-Features/Ethernet-Bridging-VLANs/VLAN-aware-Bridge-Mode-for-Large-scale-Layer-2-Environments/) (and [newer](https://docs.cumulusnetworks.com/cumulus-linux/Layer-2/Ethernet-Bridging-VLANs/VLAN-aware-Bridge-Mode/#large-bond-set-configuration)) examples about this:

> Consider the following example bridge:
>
> ```
> auto bridge
> iface bridge
>   bridge-vlan-aware yes
>   bridge-ports swp1 swp9
>   bridge-vids 2-100
>   bridge-pvid 101
>   bridge-stp on
> ```
>
> Here is the VLAN membership for that configuration:
>
> ```
> cumulus@switch$ bridge -c vlan show
> portvlan ids
> swp1 101 PVID Egress Untagged
>  2-100
>
> swp9 101 PVID Egress Untagged
>  2-100
>
> bridge 101
> ```

The configuration file used is the [*interfaces* file from ifupdown2](https://manpages.debian.org/ifupdown2/interfaces.5) (and its [addons](https://manpages.debian.org/ifupdown2/ifupdown-addons-interfaces.5)), actually developed by Cumulus Networks to replace [ifupdown](https://manpages.debian.org/ifupdown/interfaces.5), with a mostly compatible syntax, but much improved bridge and VLAN support.

---

Note 2

I didn't find any evidence of some special flag automatically flooding all VLANs to a bridge port. This [kernel commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=8adff41c3d259eb5e313b7b04669eee545925154) tells VID 4095 is documented in IEEE 802.1Q to have restrictions but allowed to be used *for management operations* as a wildcard match for the VID, but Linux doesn't seem to use such method.